# Click to show other edits triggers even when you click somewhere else, even when you're making an edit (discarding your work)

Tags: bug, edits, editor

Last week while editing [a post I just made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393850/can-num-be-atomic-for-an-int-num/39396999#39396999), another user made some helpful improvements to it.  The usual message appear in the top bar: "This post has been edited 1 time since you began. Your edit can only be saved if it is more thorough than the currently saved edit."

I left-clicked (or middle-clicked to scroll, I forget which) to the right of the textbox showing the post being edited, so the keyboard focus would leave the textbox.  I definitely did *not* click on the topbar, or on the full-width button above the textbox that had the "click to refresh" text.

The textbox closed, discarding my edits, and showed me just the newly edited version of the post.  Clicking "edit" again in the same tab didn't get me back to the edit I'd been working on for at least 20 minutes.  Instead, it just started a new edit (but with the "This post has been edited 1 time since you began..." bar still showing across the top.)

My browser is Chromium 51.0.2704.79, the Ubuntu 15.10 package.

---

I didn't see anything in the Javascript console that looked like a clear sign, but I've since closed the tab.  Other than ad-block messages, there was only one message in the console.  I wish I'd copied it, but I think it was something like a network-unreachable (and it didn't have a timestamp).  I remember thinking at the time it didn't seem likely to explain anything.

I do use uMatrix to block some things, but I have everything (except cookies/plugins) allowed from 3rd-party sites for stackoverflow.com, except for uMatrix's standard blacklist of domains that are just adds/tracking:

```
uMatrix blocked sites (scripts, cookies, etc.)
adzerk.net /  static.adzerk.net
google-analytics.com  /  www.google-analytics.com
quantserve.com /  edge.quantserve.com
scorecardresearch.com /  b.scorecardresearch.com
```

---

**Update**:

I just had this happen again, while editing [another user's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549476/assembly-language-completing-the-program-to-get-the-midstring#39549476).

After the click-to-refresh button appeared above the textbox, **I left-clicked inside the question-body textbox**.  The textbox closed.  This happened on the first click after the button appeared.

After that, the user made another edit (while I didn't have the editor open), and a middle-click to scroll refreshed the page with the edit.  My current theory is that click-to-refresh is triggering on clicks anywhere in the page!

When trying to navigate away from the page, I got the dialog prompt about modified text, stay/leave.  I don't see any way to recover the edit you were working on, though.

```
The JS console:
http://static.adzerk.net/ados.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
http://edge.quantserve.com/quant.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
http://b.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

---

In both cases, I was using the in-line editor, not the edit-in-a-separate-page editor (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39549476/edit).